# All the Planes going through intersection of two planes

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm looking for a proof of the following theorem:

If P1 written as : $A = px + qy + rz +d = 0$ and P2 written as  $B = p'x + q'y + r'z + d' = 0$

All the planes going through the line intersection of P1 and P2 can be written as:
$$A+mB = 0$$
 It means that the plane A + mB = 0 and P1 and P2 have the same line intersection.

Comment: Can plane $B$ be written in this form? I think you want the form $k_1A+k_2B=0,$ where $k_1,k_2$ are not both zero.

Comment: @coffeemath I dont excatly know what it really is but its written in this form in my text book and It seems to solve pretty hard problems easily like : find the plane which goes through A and  B intersection and point P.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is the plane $x=0$ and $B$ the plane $y=0.$ Then $A+mB=0$ becomes $x+my=0,$ but no choice of $m$ will make this $y=0.$